# Zurb Foundation: Want horizontal scrollbar

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="item">ITEMS GO HERE</div> 
        <div class="item">ITEMS GO HERE</div>
        ... many .item here ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Each `.item` would have a fixed width, say `150px`. I want the div `large-12` to be scrollable if there are more `.item` that it can fit within the current screen. How can I do that? Currently, if I add too many `.item`, then they go to the next line!

Thanks

Comment: Why are you fixing the width of the `.items` in a responsive layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add an `overflow-x:scroll;` and `white-space:nowrap;` to the parent container. And a `display:inline-block;` to the `.item`s.

Here's a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/DPGjL/)**.